RGB keyboard brightness asus rog zephyrus g16 2024 with ubuntu 24.04
I have the asus rog zephyrus g14 2024 gu605mv, the keyboard lights have the default windows setting (rainbow). How can I control it in ubuntu 24.04? at least the light intensity, whether to turn it off or on... I have tried xset and other methods but they don't work. The keyboard is RGB.

Check to see of OpenRGB (https://openrgb.org/) is compatible with your system. You can install OpenRGB as .deb or as Flatpak.
